# Using egrep and regular expression together

Tags: bash, sh

I want to search the below text file for words that ends in _letter, and get the whole portion upto "**::**". There is no space between any letter

```
blahblah:/blahblah::abc_letter:/blahblah/blahblah
blahblah:/blahblah::cd_123_letter:/blahblah/blahblah
blahblah:::/blahblah::24_cde_letter:/blahblah/blahblah
blahblah::/blahblah::45a6_letter:/blahblah/blahblah
blahblah:/blahblah::fgh_letter:/blahblah/blahblah
blahblah:/blahblah::789_letter:/blahblah/blahblah
```

I tried

```
egrep -o '*_letter'
```

and

```
egrep -o "*_letter"
```

But it only returns the word `_letter`

then I want to feed the input to the parametre of a shell script for loop. So the script will look like following

```
for i in [grep command]

     mkdir $i

end
```

It will create the following directories

```
abc_letter/
cd_123_letter/
24_cde_letter/
45a6_letter/
fgh_letter/
789_letter/
```

ps: The result between :: and _letter doesn't contain any special character, only alphanumeric character

also my system doesn't have perl

Answer (score 1):

To extract after `:` to `_letter` strings from a `file.txt` and use them in your for loop, you can use the following egrep and revise your: `script.sh`, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(egrep -o "[^:]+_letter" file.txt); do
    mkdir -p $i
done
```

Then you run `./script.sh`, and later you check with `ls`, you see:

```
$ ls -1
24_cde_letter
45a6_letter
789_letter
abc_letter
cd_123_letter
fgh_letter
file.txt
script.sh
```

### Explanation

- Your original `egrep -o '*_letter'` probably just confused bash filename expansion with regular expression,
- In bash, `*something` uses star globbing character to match `*` = `anything here` + `something`.
- However in regular expression star `*` means the preceding character zero or more times. Since `*` is at the beginning of what you wrote, there is nothing before it, so it does not match anything there.
- The only thing egrep can match is `_letter`, and since we are using the `-o` option it only displays the match, on an individual line, and thus why you originally only saw a line of `_letter` matches

Our new changes:

- `egrep` pattern starts with `[^` ... `]`, a negation, matches the opposite of what characters you put within. We put `:` within.
- The `+` says to match the preceding one or more times.
- So combined, it says look for anything-but-`:`, and do this one or more times.
- Thus of course it matches anything after `:`, and keeps matching, until the next part of the pattern
- The next part of the pattern is just `_letter`
- `egrep -o` so only matched text will be shown, one per line

So in this way, from lines such as:

```
blahblah:/blahblah::abc_letter:/blahblah/blahblah
```

It successfully extracts:

```
abc_letter
```

Then, changes to your bash script:

- Bash command substitution `$()` to have the results of the `egrep` command sent to the for-loop
- `for i value...; do` ... `done` syntax
- `mkdir -p` just a convenience in case you are re-testing, it will not error if directory was already made.

So altogether it helps to extract the pattern you wanted and generate directories with those names.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no spaces or new-lines:

```
for i in $(sed 's/^.*:\([^/]*_letter\):.*$/\1/g' infile); do
    mkdir $i
done
```

Comment: Quoting OP: `The result between :: and _letter doesn't contain any special character, only alphanumeric character`